# Saving numbers and calculations in a string by using 2D array give unexpected outputs

Tags: arrays, c, string

So here is a simple code that saves numbers and calculations one by one.
Basically what I want to do is saving all numbers and calculations in one 2D array by using if/else if

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    char newString[100][100];
    char temp[100];
    int i, j, ctr, count = 0;
    gets(str1);

    j = 0;
    ctr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= (strlen(str1)); i++)
    {
        // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
        if (str1[i] == ' ' || str1[i] == '\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j] = '\0';
            ctr++; //for next word
            j = 0; //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else if(str1[i]=='+'||str1[i]=='-'||str1[i]=='*'||str1[i]=='/'){
            ctr++; //for next word
            j = 0; //for next word, init index to 0
            newString[ctr][j] = str1[i];
            ctr++; //for next word
            j = 0; //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j] = str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ctr; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", newString[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I put **'143 + 2/3 + 23'** , what I expected is

```
143
+
2
/
3
+
23
```

But what I got is

```
143

+

2
/
3

+

23
```

There are some spaces between elements... can anyone help me what makes this kind of problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code? The problem wil be very apparent if you observe the current string whilst the program writes output to the terminal.

Comment: The problem is due to empty strings. If you expect your input to separate operands and operations with 'space' (if ' '), then do not increment ctr in else if { }, twice. The upper ctr++; j=0; is inserting a empty string.  If you do not expect operand and operation separated with space, then null terminate the string in else if(str1[i]=='+-*/'), after every ctr++, and simply skip any space (if(str1[i]=='  ')).

Comment: `gets` has been flagged as obsolete since mid 90s. You might want to update your source of learning to something that isn't outdated since 25 years back.